# Перевод координат из декартовых в сферические

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Имеется трехмерная сфера с координатами в декартовой плоскости. Необходимо получить уравнение данной сферы в системе сферических координат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что нет волшебного слова "и быстро!"...

Comment: `R = 1` *(8 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Qwertiy - а c++ зачем оставили?

Comment: @Igor спасибо, но чему равны другие 2 параметра, такие как зенитный и азимутальный углы?

Comment: @user513323 чему угодно - в своей области определения. Кстати, зенитный угол (`j`) изменяется от -90 до 90 градусов.

Answer (score 6):

Ну, раз уж из формул получается несмещенная сфера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то в сферических координатах [image: введите сюда описание изображения] получается просто: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но "*трехмерная сфера в декартовой плоскости*" - это круто... :)